# Yii2 Loading Page/Image when Bootstrap Modal is still Loading

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I have this modal:

```
<?php
    echo Html::button(
        'Create New Staff',
        [
            'value' => Url::to(['create-new-staff']),
            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-create',
            'id' => 'modalButton'
        ]);

    Modal::begin(['id' => 'modal']);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";     
    Modal::end();
?>
```

Here's my sample loading indicator image:

```
<img src="http://dkclasses.com/images/loading.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
```

When I click the modal button, I want to display a loading screen or image when the modal is still loading instead of just plainly waiting for the modal to load. I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("modalButton").click(function(event) {
        $.post( "/echo/json/", { delay: 2 } );
        $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
            $("#loading-indicator").show();
            }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
            $("#loading-indicator").hide();
            $("#modalContent").show();
         });
    });
</script>
```

I based that script in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3uhLvbn/).

And I also tried those I have searched in the internet. None of them worked. I think it's because I am using Yii. I'm not sure. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How such javascript problems can be related to Yii?

Comment: nothing. just a wild notion.

Comment: try this http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$('#modalButton').click(function (){
    $('#modal').find('#modalContent').html("")
        .load($(this).attr('value'), function(){
            var thisModal = $('#modal');
            setTimeout(function(){
                thisModal.modal('show');
                $("#loading-indicator").hide();
            }, 1000);
        });
    $("#loading-indicator").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because loading of modal window primarily depends on ajax request, you can show indicator right before it and hide in callback, something like this:

```
...
$("#loading-indicator").show();
$.post(
    "/echo/json/",
    { delay: 2 },
    function(data) {
        ...
        $("#loading-indicator").hide();
    }
);
...
```

Comment: thanks. but the code doesn't work for me. I put your code inside `$("modalButton").click(function(event)`

Comment: Is the error somewhere? Or indicator stays unactive?

Comment: there's no error as I inspect element. when I click the button, I can't see the image.

Comment: Check if ajax request is executed and if indicator's selector is valid.